# Google Maps shortest distance

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a dataset with start (X) and end (Y) coordinates. I want to extract the shortest distance from X to Y using Google Maps. Is there any package/function I can use to do this in R?

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look the the ggmap package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dave2e is right. use the function `mapdist()` from `library(ggmap)`. It has also an argument to set the type of distance to compute (see function argument `mode = c("driving", "walking", "bicycling")`). Remember that google maps api limits to 2500 element queries a day.

Comment: Does mapdist gives the shortest route?